# Exact formula for the $n$ th prime

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

There is an exact $n$th prime number formula from  [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFormulas.html)

> A double sum for the *n*th prime *p<sub>n</sub>* is $$p_n=1+\sum_{k=1}^{2(\lfloor n\ln n\rfloor+1)}\Biggl[1-\Biggl\lfloor\frac{\sum_{j=2}^k 1+\lfloor s(j)\rfloor}n\Biggr\rfloor\Biggr],\tag{13}$$ where $$s(j)\equiv-\frac{\sum_{s=1}^j \bigl(\bigl\lfloor\frac js\bigr\rfloor-\bigl\lfloor\frac{j-1}s\bigr\rfloor\bigr)-2}j\tag{14}$$

I tried to check it numerically but there is no correct answer :

```
s[j_] := -(Sum[(Floor[j/s] - Floor[(j - 1)/s]) - 2, {s, 1, j}]/j)

p[n_] := 1 + Sum[1 - Floor[Sum[1 + Floor[s[j]], {j, 2, k}]/n], {k, 1, 
2*(Floor[n Log[n]] + 1)}]


p[30]
```

> -1106

Comment: Note that the website cites this: http://www.gallup.unm.edu/~smarandache/articulo/artic.htm

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=6V_zAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA166)?

Comment: @J.M. Are you saying mathworld (and UNM) simply mistate the formula?

Comment: Looks like it. Thus: `s[j_] := 2 (1 + Sum[Floor[(j - 1)/s] - Floor[j/s], {s, 1, Sqrt[j]}])/j`

Comment: @J.M. hence there is a mistake in mathword article

Answer (score 2):

[J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m)'s correction:

```
s[j_] := 2 (1 + Sum[⌊(j - 1)/s⌋ - ⌊j/s⌋, {s, 1, Sqrt[j]}])/j

p[n_] := 1 + Sum[1 - ⌊Sum[1 + ⌊s[j]⌋, {j, 2, k}]/n⌋, {k, 1, 2*(⌊n Log[n]⌋ + 1)}]

p[30]       (* 113 *)

Prime[30]   (* 113 *)
```

Comment: I'd use `Quotient[]` instead of `Floor[]` + division myself (just like in the article I linked to). Nevertheless, it should be emphasized that this is of course an expensive way to generate primes.